# Adding Attribute to Form Element Using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, str-replace, readonly

I'm using a CMS and a form builder extension, the extension allows me to run PHP scripts when on page load.

I'm also able to add custom 'Additional Attributes' to individual elements, the 'Additional Attributes' section is a free text field allowing me to enter custom text e.g. `maxlength="20"`, `placeholder="Admin Only"` you can see below.

I have a form that contains the following elements (showing only four for brevity, actual form contains many more);

```
// user fields
<input type="text" value="" name="form[Name]" id="Name" class="form-control" maxlength="20">
<input type="text" value="" name="form[Address]" id="Address" class="form-control" maxlength="20">
// admin only fields
<input type="text" value="" name="form[AdminName]" id="AdminName" class="form-control" maxlength="20" placeholder="Admin Only">
<input type="text" value="" name="form[AdminComment]" id="AdminComment" class="form-control" maxlength="50" placeholder="Admin Only">
```

Using **only** PHP (and not a DOM Parser) I need to be able to add the `readonly` attribute all form elements that are for *admins only*. In the form above that is the last two inputs.

```
<?php
    if (userid == something) {
        // add 'readonly' attribute to all admin inputs
    } 
?>
```

I was thinking of using `str_replace` or the form 'Additional Attributes' feature somehow?

I can't use Javascript / JQuery.

Comment: Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Why is that not an option? It is using PHP.

Comment: If you were *"thinking of using `string_replace()`"* can you show us how you tried that?

Comment: BTW, the DOM parser packages are native to PHP, so it would be using PHP.

Comment: You've been here long enough and have enough reputation to know that we typically just don't write up an answer as a "try".  Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JayBlanchard It's fine if you don't know the answer, but i'd prefer to leave the questions up for a while, perhaps someone can help me. I feel that I've provided enough information in my question and demonstrated effort, if not then I'm sure the question will be closed. Thanks.

Comment: Demonstrated effort? There is no code demonstrating effort in this question *at all*. Look, I am trying to help you out, but you have to help me (and others) help you. Do you want me to show you how to do a string replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to add a custom attribute to the html element e.g. `xyz`, then use `str_replace` in order to replace this attribute with `readonly`.

The form inputs weer generated from a PHP variable `$formData`.

```
<input type="text" value="" name="form[Name]" id="Name" class="form-control" maxlength="20" xyz>

<?php
    if (userid == something) {
        str_replace("xyz","readonly",$formData)
    } 
?>
```